# Where can I view Apex job details?

Tags: apex, scheduled-job

There are some scheduled Apex jobs in Setup -> Environments -> Jobs -> Scheduled Jobs that I'd like to reassign to a different user so that I can deactivate the one they are currently assigned to (limited licenses...). However it seems the only way to do this is to delete and re-create these jobs. My question is, where can I see the information on these jobs so I can accurately recreate them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this information by querying the [`CronTrigger`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) and [`CronJobDetail`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) objects:

```
SELECT CronJobDetail.Name, CronExpression, OwnerId 
FROM CronTrigger 
WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'
```

`JobType` 7 is Scheduled Apex.

The `CronExpression` is the critical Cron timing string that you can pass to `System.schedule()`, which allows for types of schedules that are not supported in the user-interface scheduler; that will let you rebuild the jobs on the same schedule as you expect.

The easiest place I am aware of that you can see the Apex class name, frustratingly, is the job's detail page under Scheduled Jobs in Setup:

[image: Screen shot of Setup UI]

You can find Apex class names from the `AsyncApexJob` object, which represents the queued run of the scheduled job, but I'm not aware of any way other than visual inspection to correlate the `AsyncApexJob` back to the parent `CronTrigger` (its `ParentJobId` is blank). Regardless, you can query

```
SELECT ApexClass.Name FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'ScheduledApex'
```

You'll be able to view the actual class code only if it's not part of a managed package.

You can schedule a job programmatically by opening Anonymous Apex in the Developer Console and entering

```
System.schedule('My Job Name', '0 0 * * * ?', new MySchedulableClass());
```

The second argument is your `CronExpression` from the `CronTrigger` query.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help David, I really appreciate this. Where in SF would I run this query?

Comment: In the Query Editor in Developer Console.

Comment: Got it, that's useful. One last question, can I see the code in the class being scheduled anywhere?

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit. Unfortunately you have to jump through some hoops to collect all of these data points.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update to David Reed's answer, apparently as of v53 there is a relationship between AsyncApexJob and CronTrigger, CronTrigger is a Lookup from AsyncApexJob. Thusly:

```
SELECT ApexClass.Name, crontrigger.CronJobDetail.Name, crontrigger.CronExpression, crontrigger.OwnerId 
FROM AsyncApexJob 
WHERE crontrigger.CronJobDetail.JobType = '7' and JobType = 'ScheduledApex'
```

Unfortunately, the Dev Console UI is still not very good and you see some of the results as [Object Object], but it helps somewhat. Personally I added a WHERE crontrigger.OwnerId = 'some_id' to help our Admin find the jobs running under a prior User we need to Deactivate.